# Where the center of gravity be for an umbilic torus?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Due to its unusual shape I am unsure if the COG would be right in the center of closer to the side with (what looks like) more mass on the outside?

Comment: If the centre of mass of any thin "slice" lies on the same circle centered in the origin and there is a uniform mass distribution, the center of gravity still lies in the origin.

Comment: Ok so then I would say it is not in the center since the slices would be radial from the center leading to uneven mass distribution.